# Is there any way to check if a lambda function has been idle for a given amount of time?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have one use case where I am supposed to execute a piece of code based on idle time of a given lambda function, I mean if given function has been idle for say 5 mins,  my piece of code should run.
Is there any way to check the lambda state/status?

Comment: How do you define "idle time" for an AWS Lambda function? Why is the function 'idle'? Why is somebody asking you to do this (that is, what is the bigger use-case that they want to achieve)?

Comment: I have one lambda function which has subscribed to an SNS topic and once lambada function is done consuming all the SNS events, I need to downgrade the provision concurrency of that lambda function. That is why I wanted to  know if there is anyway to know that lambada function has been idle for some time meaning, it is not processing any SNS events. 
Hope that explains my use case a bit better.

Comment: Please note that AWS Lambda functions do not "consume SNS events". Rather, when a message is sent to an Amazon SNS topic and a Lambda function is subscribed to the topic, Amazon SNS will trigger the Lambda function with the message. Thus, the Lambda function only runs as a result of a message being sent to the SNS topic, and then stops running after the message has been processed. The Lambda function does not sit there waiting to consume messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking to avoid lambda cold starts, please leverage Provisioned Concurrency which will have lambda running up with the amount of concurrency setup
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-provisioned-concurrency-for-lambda-functions/

If you did not mean this, then I assume idleness as "no requests processed" by lambda, if yes, then use cloudwatch metric/alarm to monitor # of invocations over a timeframe and then do whatever in its action

Comment: Second part of your answer is what I am looking for, but question is how to find out "no requests processed"  for a given lambda function? Is there any way in cloudwatch to do it?

Comment: Lambda CW Metric: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-invocation
Creating CW Alarm, use the metric and dimensions from above link and create alarm using below link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ConsoleAlarms.html